# GCP Cloud Run Limits

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, google-cloud-run

Hi I have a question concerning cloud run because I use it to **scrape** data with headless chrome.
The thing is that my scraping last more than 15min (limit of cloud run) , do you know any other application on GCP i could use as a substitute ?
Thank you so much .

Comment: Longer timeouts are on the roadmap for Cloud Run. Also you can use Cloud Run for Anthos (which is the same experience on a GKE cluster). That platform has longer or unlimited timeouts (you can configure it beyond 15 minutes), and it works in rather similar fashion.

Comment: Today, given your requirements, use Compute Engine (GCE) - f1-micro at about $7/month (free with the Free Trail). Compute Engine does not include the Cloud Run features such as custom domains, load balancing, simple deployments, fault tolerance, etc. For a low-cost VM in the cloud, GCE is a good service for you use case.

Comment: How do you trigger your app? Does your process in resumeable in case of interuption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has lifted the request timeout to **60 minutes** (in beta)

> Important: Although Cloud Run (fully managed) has a maximum timeout of
> 60 minutes, only timeouts up to 15 minutes are generally available.
> Setting timeouts greater than 15 minutes is a Beta feature.

You can read more about it here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout

Comment: The link now suggests 60 minutes is the new GA value (I don't see any beta mentioned there).